# Issue adding key value pair to key in python

Tags: python-3.x

Within a loop, I am trying to add key & value pair to my json file.

In the first iteration, the json-file is always empty.

In the second iteration, I want to add a new key & value to my key "articles". But this do not work. I get an issue.

Thank you for your hints!

**issue:**

```
list indices must be integers or slices, not set
```

**my approach:**

```
keywordJson = [{'articles': [{'id': filename, 'phrases': phrases}]}]

with open(json_path, "r+", encoding='utf-8') as json_file:
    if i == 0:
        json_decoded = keywordJson
        json.dump(keywordJson, json_file, ensure_ascii=False)       
    else:
        json_decoded = json.load(json_file)
        json_decoded[{"articles"}] = [{"id": filename, "phrases": phrases}]
        json.dump(json_decoded, json_file, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say `[{"articles" : <whatever>}]`, the square brackets indicate that this data structure is a list containing a single element, which is a dictionary. Thus, you'd need something like:

```
json_decoded[0]["articles"] = [{"id": filename, "phrases": phrases}]
```

I'm not sure you actually want all those lists in there, though. This might be cleaner:

```
keywordJson = {'articles': {'id': filename, 'phrases': phrases}}
```

And then the code would be:

```
json_decoded["articles"] = {"id": filename, "phrases": phrases}
```